# Sorting dynamic 3D array aplhabetically by KEY sets

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

Although there are many similar topics to this post, there is no duplication to it in this forum and on web, OR maybe there is but I couldn't find it.

What I need to is to sort this array alphabetically by KEYs. The problem is, all the KEYs are dynamic so there is STATIC thing to rely on.

Beside other posts, I also looked at PHPs sorting functions like multisort, ksor etc.

Wrongly listed:
Under ACADEMIC, [Students] and [Staff]
Under MARKETING [Applications] and [Activity]

Thanks in advance

**ARRAY**

```
Array
(
    [ACADEMIC] => Array
        (
            [Communications] => Array
                (
                    [Email] => academic/email
                    [Sms] => academic/sms
                )

            [Exams] => Array
                (
                    [Assessments] => academic/assessments
                )

            [Students] => Array
                (
                    [Progress] => academic/progress
                )

            [Staff] => academic/staff
        )

    [ACCOUNTS] => Array
        (
            [Order] => accounts/order
        )

    [ADMIN] => Array
        (
            [Menus] => admin/menus
            [Permissions] => admin/permissions
            [Roles] => admin/roles
            [Users] => admin/users
        )

    [AGENTS] => Array
        (
            [New] => agents/new
        )

    [MARKETING] => Array
        (
            [Applications] => Array
                (
                    [Edit] => marketing/edit
                    [New] => marketing/new
                )

            [Activity] => marketing/activity
        )

)
```

Comment: `Wrongly listed:....` section is self explanatory for the title and content.

Comment: Wrongly listed what???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $inner)
{
   ksort($array[$key]);
}
```